# Save results of a call into a Context Parameter using VS Load Testing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a recorded Visual Studio Load Test (using Visual Studio 2015).

It seems to have recorded fine, but if I just play it back as it is, I am going to get primary key violations.

I have logic like this in my application:

1. Ask the web service for an ID.
2. Take that ID and pass it into a save call.

I know that I can put in the value of a "Context Parameter" using `{{ variable }}` syntax.

But I have not been able to find a way save a value off at run time into a Context Parameter.

**Is there a way to take part of a result and then use it for future calls?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to add an [extraction rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182545(v=vs.110).aspx) to the request. There are several types of extraction rule for getting different types of data from the response. They are added via the context (right click) menu of the requests. Select the required extraction rule and set the properties as needed.

More complicated extractions can be done by [writing your own extraction rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243179(v=vs.120).aspx) or by writing a [Plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514192(v=vs.110).aspx).

If the text to be extracted can be selected in the "Response" tab of the web test execution results then, sometimes, the context menu of that selected text has a "Add extraction rule" entry (I may have mis-remembered the exact wording). If using this then check the rule that is added. It often creates a rule looking for a very short `Starts with` string and looking for the Nth occurrence. Eg, in HTML the text `Value="` is common and the generated rule might be to find the 17th occurence of `alue=`. The rule may be a good starting point but works better to select the first (ie index `0`) occurrence of a longer string.

(Little or nothing has changed between the 2010 and the 2015 versions of Visual Studio as far as the referenced articles are concerned.)

Comment: Thank you!  Excellent Answer!